# Populating reaxt ag grid after API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, redux-thunk, ag-grid-react

I am new to react and stuck at this point.
I am doing an async API call in action dispatcher to fetch a list of patient data.Once the data is returned I need to render it in ag grid.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPatientsStartAsync } from '../../redux/patients/patients.actions';
import { PatientContainer } from './patients.styles';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';

const PatientsComponent = ({ patients, isFetching, fetchPatientsStartAsync }) => {

const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([]);

const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchPatientsStartAsync();
  if (!isFetching && patients) {
  setColumnDefs([
    { headerName: 'UID', field: 'UID'},
    { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name'},
    { headerName: 'Cataract Status', field: 'cataractStatus'},
    { headerName: 'Retina Status', field: 'retinaStatus'},
  ]);
  setRowData(patients);
}
}, [fetchPatientsStartAsync]);

if (!patients ) {
return (
    <>
      <h4>No Patient data for today</h4>
    </>
  )
}
return (
  <>
    <PatientContainer>
      <h1>Patient's Page</h1>
      <div>
        <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={ {height: '50vh'} }>
          <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={rowData}>
          </AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </PatientContainer>
  </>
)
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  patients: state.patients.patients,
  isFetching: state.patients.isFetching
});

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPatientsStartAsync })(PatientsComponent);
```

And this is my fetchPatientsStartAsync() inside patients.actions.js:

```
export const fetchPatientsStartAsync = () => {
return async dispatch => {
dispatch(fetchPatientStart());
  try {
    const patients = await fetchPatients.fetchPatients();
    console.log('Fetched Patients: ', patients);
    dispatch(fetchPatientsSuccess(patients.data.patients));
  } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error: ', e);
      dispatch(fetchPatientsFailed());
    }
  }
 };
```

So In my component fetchPatientsStartAsync is running asynchronously and am unable to render data in my ag grid. Is there a way to set a callback or Promise here, so that once fetchPatientsStartAsync() is completed I can do further UI rendering. Also am using redux-thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, my problem is fixed. The issue was with styles import.
Instead of:

```
import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css';
```

I used this: (and issue was fixed)

```
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put patients in `rowData` state as props are going to updated through redux state. As I can see your columnDefs are not dynamic so you can create a constant for that as well.

```js
const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'UID', field: 'UID'},
    { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name'},
    { headerName: 'Cataract Status', field: 'cataractStatus'},
    { headerName: 'Retina Status', field: 'retinaStatus'},
]

const PatientsComponent = ({ patients, isFetching, fetchPatientsStartAsync }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPatientsStartAsync();
  }, [fetchPatientsStartAsync]);

  if (!patients ) {
    return <h4>No Patient data for today</h4>
  }
  return (
    <>
      <PatientContainer>
        <h1>Patient's Page</h1>
        <div>
          <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={ {height: '50vh'} }>
            <AgGridReact
              columnDefs={columnDefs}
              rowData={patients}>
            </AgGridReact>
          </div>
        </div>
      </PatientContainer>
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested, but still no luck

Comment: Is your state updating properly in redux?

Comment: yes, I checked it in redux devtools, it is geting updated. Check this: https://ibb.co/JyWWN13

Comment: Can you give a link to reproducible example?

Comment: right now my code is in embroyonic stage and backend part is also locally only not deployed anywhere, so it's difficult to share a link, but will try if I can

Comment: If you are managing the state of grid in your React component then you should try implementing `deltaRowDataMode` as:
`<AgGridReact
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    rowData={patients}
    deltaRowDataMode
    getRowNodeId={data => data.id}
/>`
You can use `data.id` or any other unique key in `getRowNodeId` callback.

Comment: I am not aware of deltaRowDataMode, is it something provided by ag-grid?? I will do a google a check it out, though. thanks