# Updating ag-grid with new data after new table load with React

Tags: react-redux, ag-grid

I'm using React and I have a navigation component that updates a Redux table state. Based on the table chosen in the navigation, I need the ag-grid to update accordingly.

I have six tables. Three of them have the same column definitions. I'm currently using `onNewColumnsLoaded` to refresh the data, but because three of the tables have the same column definitions, nothing's loading. I've tried `onColumnEverythingChanged` and other column options, but again because the columns are the same nothing is happening.

I've tried `rowDataChanged`, `rowDataUpdated`, and `componentStateChanged`, but those refresh the data if I'm scrolling or filtering, so those are not acceptable options.

I've taken a look at [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609871/ag-grid-updating-values-pushed) but it's using plain javascript, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59936187/populating-reaxt-ag-grid-after-api-call) has a problem in the css, not in the javascript.

What's the best way to have the grid update programmatically based on Redux state variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to use immutableData with directly udpate the rowData:

```
getRowNodeId
```

method should be implemented as well.

Check the [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-immutable-data/) for more detail.